# replace a string with another string in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table containing column image. In image column values are stored like abc.png,xyz.png,agh.png. Now i want to update the column with xyz.png,agh.png. i used following code. but its not working. Please help me. your help would be appreciated.

```
update table set images=(select REPLACE(images,'45021.jpg',' ') from table where id='6') where id='6'
```

sql is showing following error : 
You can't specify target table 'table' for update in FROM clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to make subselect for this.

```
UPDATE `table`
   SET `images` = REPLACE(`images`, '45021.jpg', ' ')
 WHERE `id`= 6
```

Answer (score 0):

table  is yourtablename??

```
 update tablename set images=REPLACE(images,'45021.jpg',' ') where id='6'
```